# How do I remove duplicated template inheritance in Mobile and Desktop with Jinja2?

Tags: html, flask, bootstrap-4, jinja2

### Problem

- My code has navigation for only mobile.
- I would like to remove duplicated template inheritance in Mobile(sm) and Desktop(md lg).
- The following {% block main_content %}{% endblock %} code is duplicated and contains a lot of graphs.

### Question

- How do I remove duplicated template inheritance?

### Development Environment

- Bootstrap4
- Jija2 (Flask or responer)

Does anybody have a solution for my problem?
Best regards,

template_parent.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs d-md-none d-sm-block" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    {% block main_content %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-none d-md-block">
    {% block main_content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

child.html

```html
{% extends "layout/main.html" %}

{% block main_content %}
a lot of graphs
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove duplicate code below code

```
<div class="d-none d-md-block">
    {{Foo}}
</div>
```

And instead to go to add duplicate blocks for mobile and web, you just need to add one block of code for mobile and desktop and add/update classes on its parent container based on the screen sizes.

we have javascript object `window.navigator.platform` which gives you the platform you are using. Based on that platform and `window.innerWidth` you can add/update classes of your graph container.

Comment: Thanks your answer, but I want to use duplicated template inheritances in Jinja2.  How do I remove this?

Answer (score 1):

A media query consists of an optional media type (all, handheld, print, TV and so on) and any number of optional expressions that limit when the query will trigger, such as width, pixel-density or orientation. Media queries are part of CSS3, and enable developers to customize their content for different presentations of their content.

For mobile use:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) {
     your code {
           display: none;
 }
}
```

Same for desktop, but different width.